# I don't know what i did wrong on my code, the error message for php form validation stopped working

Tags: php, css, validation

I don't know what I did wrong on my code, the error message for php form validation stopped working.

It was working perfectly until i added value attribute to the input so that the user input will persist even if the page refresh and didn't deliver due to typeError.

The form does'nt show any error again but my reason for adding the value attribute is working.

I'm learning php, please help me to understand why i'm having the issue.
I don't understand because i'm not getting any error from php.

This is my code

```
<?php

// empting the value variables when user have'nt typed anything to prevent error. This is the shorthand of typing samething that's going to have the same value
$email = $title = $ingredients = '';

// put out the error on the html instead of echoing it
// so i used array so that i can neatly put out all the errors instead of using different variables for all
$error = array('email' => '', 'title' => '', 'ingredients' => '');

// check if the form was clicked and retrive the values sent
// i will achieve this by using a default method called isset() and i will check if value is contained in the form using the submit btn, this is because when a user clicks on the form submit, the user have entered a value
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // check if the field submited is empty
    // we achieve this using a default method called empty()
    // we check them one field at a time


    // check for email
    if(empty($_POST['email'])){
      $error['email'] = ' Email is empty';
    } else {
      $email =  $_POST['email'];
    }

    // check for title
    if(empty($_POST['title'])){
      $error['title'] = ' Title is empty';
    }  else {
      $title =  $_POST['title'];
    }

    // check for ingredients
    if(empty($_POST['ingredients'])){
      $error['ingredients'] = ' Ingredients is empty';
    }  else {
      $ingredients =  $_POST['ingredients'];
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <?php include 'template/header.php'?>
  

  <form action="form.php" method="POST">

  <div class="input_div">
  <label >Email :</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" value=" <?php echo $email ?> ">
  <div class="error_msg"><?php echo $error['email']; ?></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="input_div" >
  <label >Pizza Title :</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value=" <?php echo $title ?> " >
    <div class="error_msg"><?php echo $error['title']; ?></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="input_div" >
  <label >Ingredients (comma seperated) :</label>
    <input type="text" name="ingredients" value=" <?php echo $ingredients ?> ">
    <div class="error_msg"><?php echo $error['ingredients']; ?></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="input_div" >
  <input type="submit" class="submitBtn" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
  
  </form>


  <?php include 'template/footer.php' ?>

</html>
```

Comment: _"and didn't deliver due to typeError."_ - Please expand on this. Do you get an error? If yes, add it to your question (the full error message.)

Comment: `value=" <?php echo $email ?> "` - A space is a non-empty value so those two spaces around the email (even if `$email` is empty) will post a string with two spaces instead of an empty value. It will look empty in the form, but `empty()` will return false. Change it to: `value="<?php echo $email ?>"` (without the spaces). Do the same for the other inputs as well.

Comment: sidenote, you should set $error empty array not populate it with the keys, then you can do `if(empty($error)) {//do something}` as-is your code would need to check if all the keys are empty rather then just checking if the array is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other then the issues with whitespace in your inputs you should also be aware of XSS when inserting the values back into the form (like using `"` would break the form) and also don't populate the errors till needed, this will allow you to easily continue and do the success step without needing to loop over the $errors array and it also allows you to hide the `<div class="error_msg"></div>` element and only show when there is an error.

Also your missing `<head>` and `<body>`, presuming they are in the includes, but doing it that way would make it rather difficult to add additional elements or scripts.

```
<?php

$email = $title = $ingredients = '';

$error = [];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    // check for email
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
      $error['email'] = 'Email is empty';
    } else {
      $email =  $_POST['email'];
    }

    // check for title
    if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
      $error['title'] = 'Title is empty';
    }  else {
      $title =  $_POST['title'];
    }

    // check for ingredients
    if (empty($_POST['ingredients'])) {
      $error['ingredients'] = 'Ingredients is empty';
    }  else {
      $ingredients =  $_POST['ingredients'];
    }

    if (empty($error)) {
        // do some thing with $email, $title, $ingredients

        die(header('Location: ./thank-you.php'));
    }
}

function xss_safe($value) {
    return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <?php include 'template/header.php' ?>

    <form action="form.php" method="POST">

        <div class="input_div">
            <label>Email :</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?= xss_safe($email) ?>"/>
            <?= isset($error['email']) ? '<div class="error_msg">'.$error['email'].'</div>' : '' ?>
        </div>

        <div class="input_div">
            <label>Pizza Title :</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="<?= xss_safe($title) ?>"/>
            <?= isset($error['title']) ? '<div class="error_msg">'.$error['title'].'</div>' : '' ?>
        </div>

        <div class="input_div">
            <label>Ingredients (comma seperated) :</label>
            <input type="text" name="ingredients" value="<?= xss_safe($ingredients) ?>"/>
            <?= isset($error['ingredients']) ? '<div class="error_msg">'.$error['ingredients'].'</div>' : '' ?>
        </div>

        <div class="input_div">
            <input type="submit" class="submitBtn" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php include 'template/footer.php' ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as your error checking is merely for empty/missed input fields it's easier to just make the inputs required as per HTML5. Here's a simplified version using placeholders for information after the form has been submitted.

**Warning:** If you are going to be inserting this data into a MySQL table, you need to sanitize the inputs first!

```
 <?php
 $email = $title = $ingredients = "";

 if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $title = $_POST["title"];
 $ingredients = $_POST["ingredients"];
 }

 echo "
 <form method='POST'>

 <label>Email:</label>
 <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='$email' required>

 <label>Pizza Title:</label>
 <input type='text' name='title' placeholder='$title' required>

 <label>Ingredients (comma seperated):</label>
 <input type='text' name='ingredients' placeholder='$ingredients' required>

 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>

 </form>
 ";

 ?>
```

Comment: should always do server-side validation too

Comment: Yes, can't disagree and I did mention this above. Unfortunately I don't know what he's doing with the data or what the form action contains, for all I know it could be emailing this info somewhere and MySQL might not even be involved?